# Hiding the http referer headers data of the exact page path using exit page

Tags: php, http-referer, referer

I'm trying to do an exit page redirect, main purpose is to hide the http referer data of the exact page path,

I used this code as exit.php page :

```
<?php

/*
 * Sets the HTTP headers to redirect the user to a different page
 * along with settings the HTTP status code to 307 Temporary Redirect
 */
function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: {$url}", true, 307);
}

/*
 * Checks if the URL is valid and uses the HTTP or HTTPS scheme.
 */
function valid_url($url) {
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED|FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    if($scheme !== "http" && $scheme !== "https") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


if(!isset($_GET['url'])) {
    // Missing required argument. What should we do?
    redirect("/");
    exit;
}else{
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    if(valid_url($url)) {
        redirect($url);
        exit;
    }else{
        // Invalid URL. What should we do?
        redirect("/");
        exit;
    }
}
```

and then on the page I add the link like this:

```
<a href="/exit.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com">Example.com</a>
```

But when i test it using https://www.whatismyreferer.com/
I still get the exact path, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

source of code: http://geekthis.net/post/hide-http-referer-headers/

Comment: the `referrer` header is sent by the browser, I don't think you can control that from the server side, try using `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">` instead

Answer (score 8):

As I said in the comment you can't hide the Referrer from the server side (as far as I know), but there are ways to do so.

## Using a meta tag

You can tell the browser to not send a referrer by adding the meta element like this:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

## Using the referrerpolicy attribute (experimental)

You can add the `referrerpolicy` attribute to an anchor element (area, img, iframe and link too), it accepts the following value:
`no-referrer, no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url`
more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

## Using the rel attribute

You can also pass `noreferrer` to the `rel` attribute, more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

## Using the Referrer-Policy HTTP header

This HTTP header allows you to set a policy about sending the referrer, documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy), you can use it in PHP with the `header()` function like this:

`header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");`

Or in your case:

```
function redirect($url) {
    header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");
    header("Location: {$url}", true, 307);
}
```

This [article](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/) explains this feature in more details.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, if so, I'm wondering how google or Facebook does it then?

Comment: You mean not sending the referrer? they simply tell the browser not to send the referrer using one of the methods I mentioned (maybe one of them, maybe both or maybe something I'm not aware of)

Comment: I just tried this, using  https://www.whatismyreferer.com/  it hides the referrer completely, does this hide it for all the browsers?

Comment: It depends on the browser, Chrome and Firefox support it, Opera supports some policies Safari,Edge and IE from MDN they don't

Comment: @N4d I updated my answer with methods to achieve what you want with links to helpful documentations.

Comment: ^^ this was the best solution as developer sometimes I use none protected scripts and I don't want to expose my links to other sites .