# http header hide redirect location

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, routes

I am trying to hide the redirect location in my HTTP servlet response. Is it possible?
I don't want my visitor to know the link he is being routed to. I want him to see something encoded.

This is my code snippet.

```
        String res = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(param));

        String link = ServerResourceURLLinkBuilder.getResourceURL(res);
        
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        response.setHeader("Location",link);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255346/hiding-the-http-referer-headers-data-of-the-exact-page-path-using-exit-page

Answer (score 1):

The client *must* know the link, otherwise he can’t follow the redirect.

Although I’m not sure why you would want to hide that information, you can, alternatively:

- not do a redirect and, instead, return the resource directly
- return an obfuscated or one time use url

Comment: I don't want the end-user to guess how or what we are doing in the back-end. I wanted to have a hacker-proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to come around this issue.

I just used BuffedImage and returned a byte array in the responseServlet.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(link));
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"jpg", baos);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```